# Vtiger 6.5 show contacts in the 'detail' view of an account

Tags: crm, vtiger

How can I show contacts of an account in the 'detail' view of that account?

Answer (score 0):

It needs some more details:

which version of the CRM system?

Update: however, you can find it in the menu on the left